# Angular ng-Route doesn't work in a very simple example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular.js and found an example on w3c.school
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing

But when I try to test it it doesn't work,
I made two .htm files simply containing one word, for example "RED", or "GREEN". As simple as this example is I cannot get it to work. I think that it might be the libraries I am using

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- JavaScript Files -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <p><a href="#/">Main</a>
  </p>
  <a href="#red">Red</a>
  <a href="#green">Green</a>
  <a href="#blue">Blue</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "test.html"
      }).when("/red", {
        templateUrl: "red.htm"
      }).when("/green", {
        templateUrl: "green.htm"
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: W3Schools has *no relation whatsoever* to the official W3C. They are completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are moving towards a page "red.htm" which,... Doesn't exist in your situation! The page is already there in the directory for W3School (http://www.w3schools.com/angular/red.htm for exmaple)

So what you need to do is to create a htm page called red.htm in the same directory and thus navigate to it using routing. If you want to make the same example copy the code of the page I linked and try to run it with both files on the same directory.

Comment: I have made those files. I have red.htm and green.htm

Comment: Did you ensure to put them in the same directory as your main file?

Comment: I am working with a XAMPP setup, so all three files (test.html, red.htm and green.htm) are avaliable in .... while I was typing this I changed a few things and fixed it

Comment: Can you share what you fixed in an answer to help any future person who might face the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the three files I was using (test.html, red.html, green.html) I finally noticed/understood that you mustn't self-reference the file you are writing the script in.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/red", {
        templateUrl: "red.htm"
    }).when("/green", {
        templateUrl: "green.htm"
    });
});
</script>
```

Simply by removing the .when method for 'test.html' (which is the exact same file the code is in) the self-referencing stops, and the code is allowed to execute.